# Unit testing: Does it make sense to test parent object methods?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, tdd

Let's say I am using a framework that has a class called Animal.

```
class Animal(object):
    def speak(self):
        logging.info(self.sound)
```

I have to subclass this object in order to use it and it might look something like this:

```
class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sound = 'Woof Woof'
```

The way I see it I could do two things. The first is something like like this:

```
dog = Dog()
assert dog.sound == 'Woof Woof'
```

The second option is to mock out logging.info and check if it was called. I have mixed feelings about both of them.

The first one feels like I am just testing my configuration and the second one feels like I am not actually testing the object I want.

I am using this simple example because maybe then people that don't use Django could give me some pointers. The real problem I am having involves Django generic views.

For example I can have this template view:

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
```

Do I just test if template_name has the correct value or do I use the test client to do a higher level test to test the complete view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, make sure the parent object is tested properly (with mocking if necessary) and test the sub-objects methods separately. This fits with the encapsulation concept (making matters local).

If you don't, a large project with many classes will drain all your coding resources for no added value.

Comment: So you are saying I should do both?

Comment: @Pickels: Yes.  Test the parent and the children separately.

Comment: I started answering the question, but was pulled out. I agree with your answer, but just to eloborate.Can your question could be rephrased as, should I test functionality derived from parent class, when we unit test the child class.?

If my understanding is correct, then you need to make sure that all your components are tested. So have a test case for Parent class and a test case for child class. you need not  test parent functionality in child, unless if you are overloaded the functionality.

Comment: @Pickels yes, separately, but don't retest parent in child (unnecessary duplicate work).

Comment: So just to be clear. I need to make sure both objects are tested right? But if the parent object belongs to a framework which I presume is thoroughly tested does that mean I don't have to test it myself? Just making sure cause I am getting mixed answers.

Comment: My strategy on foreign frameworks depends on their reputation and the level of participants (i.e., vitality). If its bad, I don't even bother testing anymore, I just don't use the framework. Each time I tried, I always found a glitch down the road. And, since the titanic never makes a U turn on a dime, it has ALWAYS been costly. On the other side, I don't test frameworks having a a good reputation, because I never encountered a major issue.

Comment: When many people use a framework, bugs are always discovered and solved quickly, or the framework dies quickly... You can easily find information about frameworks. Now I ALWAYS invest time in reading this information BEFORE I start using the framework. I ask questions if necessary. It saved me a lot of time. So no, I don't test parent classes from the frameworks I trust.

Answer (score 3):

In your simple example I would probably test the parent method. But in your Django case that would mean testing Django. And that's not your job! ;-) For me that's one of the big problems of unit testing: Don't test other peoples code or 3rd part libs. Make sure that your part is correct. Might sound obvious, but is not that easy in real live - at least in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

The test that you show is exactly correct - you are repeating the string literal `'Woof Woof'` in your test.

You could have a similar test for `Animal`:

```
animal = Animal()
animal.sound = 'sound'
animal.speak()
# test that detects log contains 'sound'
```

You could also have a test that takes a list of Animals, eg `[Dog, Cat, ...]` and detects that an instance of each speaks its sound.

```
for animalClass in AnimalList:
    animal = animalClass()
    animal.speak()
    # test that detects log contains animal.sound
```